# How to configure multiplatform JFace project for Windows and Linux in Gradle?

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, gradle, jface

I am writing a cross-platform application using JFace that should run on both Windows and Linux.
Unfortunately, JFace requires different SWT versions depending on platform — it requires `org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64` on 64 bit Linux and `org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64` on 64 bit Windows.

I have come up with the following temporary solution:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

plugins {
    // ...
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.0.0"
}
// ...
val swtVersion = "3.114.100"
val swtName = "org.eclipse.swt." +
        (System.getProperty("platform") ?: OperatingSystem.current().let { current ->
            when {
                current.isLinux -> "gtk.linux"
                current.isWindows -> "win32.win32"
                current.isMacOsX -> "cocoa.macosx"
                else -> throw RuntimeException("Unsupported operating system: $current")
            }
        } + if (System.getProperty("os.arch").contains("64")) ".x86_64" else ".x86")

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.name == "org.eclipse.swt.\${osgi.platform}") {
            useTarget("${requested.group}:$swtName:${requested.version}")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation("org.eclipse.platform", "org.eclipse.jface", "3.20.0")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.example.myapp.AppKt"
}
```

It allows to build JAR that runs only on host OS with:

```sh
gradle shadowJar
```

and to cross compile for Windows with:

```sh
gradle shadowJar -Dplatform=win32.win32.x86_64
```

When ran on a wrong platform it fails (as expected) with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-win32-4934r6 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
        no swt-win32 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
        Can't load library: /home/nawordar/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-win32-4934r6.so
        Can't load library: /home/nawordar/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-win32.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:145)
        at com.example.myapp.AppKt.main(App.kt:9)
        at com.example.myapp.AppKt.main(App.kt)
```

I am looking for either of two solutions:

1. Create tasks that build JARs with different names and dependencies for each platform and a meta-task that builds both JARs at once;
2. Create one JAR that runs on both platforms.

As for the first one, I am new to Gradle and I cannot find a way to create a task that produces JAR with name specific to the platform and has platform-specific dependencies. On [this](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/custom-tasks/) website the `classifier` property is mentioned, but it is deprecated. `archiveClassifier`, that is supposed to replace it, is read-only, so I don't know how I can use it. The second problem I have with this solution is that I cannot find how to declare task specific resolution strategy.

As for the second one, I'm not sure if that is possible, but if it is, it would be a preferable solution.

Comment: One jar for all platforms is not really possible (which is why there is a different version of Eclipse for each platform for example).

Comment: @greg-449 I was able to do this with SWT only, that's why I was hopeful that it is also possible with JFace. Anyway, now as I think about it, one JAR for all platform doesn't really make sense, because I would still need to create separate installers and executables for each platform.

Comment: SWT is the main reason Eclipse has multiple versions. Personally I build small e4 style Eclipse RCPs and use maven + tycho to build - this handles building all platforms automatically.